# After add a page to my "read later" list, and go off-line, where's the page for me to read?

Tags: ios, pocket, safari

I can't find how to access the pages I added to "read later" with Safari in iOS5, any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Start Safari
2. Access bookmarks (the Book icon on the toolbar)
3. Pick 'Reading List' (Top entry in the table with the glasses icon)

Unlike InstaPaper, the Reading List just collects links (not content) so you need to be online to access the articles.

Comment: I'm not able to read off-line? Shouldn't I?

Comment: It's just a reading list (that syncs with your bookmarks), not an offline reader. For offline reading consider Instapaper.